# Scala class composition and mixin confusion

Tags: scala

I am following the Scala documentation [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/mixin-class-composition.html) and I had a few questions:

1. What is the `type T` mean? What is it for?
2. What is this syntax: `s charAt i` and `richStringIter foreach println`? What is going on here? Is `s` the recipient of the method call `charAt`?
3. Why does `RichIterator` needs to extend `AbsIterator`?
4. Is the whole point for `RichStringIter` to call `foreach` and since it extends `StringIterator`, the `foreach` method can call `next` and `hasNext` too?

The documentation doesn't explain this up until this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the type T mean? What is it for?

Type T is used as a placeholder for different data types to use as per the need. Study generics for this.

> What is this syntax: s charAt i and richStringIter foreach println?
>   What is going on here? Is s the recipient of the method call charAt?

You can think of String as an array of Char. charAt will give the character in that particular position from the String. Index starts at 0.

charAt method is applied on the String s and the Char from matching index is returned

foreach is a method that traverses all the elements of the given sequence and return Unit. i.e you can perform any task that doesn't return a value

> Why does RichIterator needs to extend AbsIterator?

Because it's a design choice to resue hasNext and next element from AbsIterator and implement foreach in RichIterator. Also AbsIterator is abstract. Think of this as a template which can be reused according to developer's choice for other applications. Please study traits and abstract class in Scala to completely understand this.

> Is the whole point for RichStringIter to call foreach and since it
>   extends StringIterator, the foreach method can call next and hasNext
>   too?

foreach is to traverse through all the elements in the sequence. This is also a type of design and a good part of Scala's trait and abstract classes. Go through Scala trait and Abstract classes. **Programming in Scala** is a good bok for this

Comment: there are no dots in between s charAt and i. Why is this?

Comment: You don't need to use dot to call functions in scala

Comment: Or between the function and its argument?

Comment: Yes you can call functions just like operator. obj.fun(param) can be written like obj fun param. For multiple arguments, this is not valid